# Dismiss keyboard for UITextView without using Return key

Tags: iphone, textview, resignfirstresponder

I'm using a UITextView and want to keep the normal usage of Return key, i.e. to insert a new line. But how do I dismiss the keyboard when I can't use the Return key for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A lot of people add a UIToolbar with a <kbd>Done</kbd> button on it above the keyboard. This is how the Safari app does it as well and in my opinion it is the best way to handle this situation. See a [pic here](http://www.nwmobiledev.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Screenshot_22.png).

To dismiss the keyboard, you just have to do `[textField resignFirstResponder];.`

[Here](http://www.randomsequence.com/articles/adding-a-toolbar-with-next-previous-above-uitextfield-keyboard-iphone/) is an okay example of how to add the UIToolbar when the keyboard shows/hides.

Comment: Great, using that solution with a inputAccessoryView for the UITextView.

Answer (score 1):

How the user triggers it is a design decision: another button, a swipe gesture?

When it's triggered, call:

```
[self.textView resignFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a background tap to hide the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to Dismiss keyboard.

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    //NSLog(@"ShouldBeginEditing");

    if(textView == indexOneTW)
    {
          here use uibutton and set its target to a method which contains 
          [urTextView resignFirstResponder] 
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you declare support for the UITextViewDelegate protocol.

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:     (NSString *)text

{

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) 
    {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;

}
```

Enjoy Buddy with this code....

Comment: Cool - That's not what he asked though

Comment: @issues : [UIView _forgetDependentConstraint:]: message sent to deallocated instance