# How to dismiss keyboard for UITextView

Tags: swift, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

The following triggers when the Done button is clicked on the keyboard.  It goes into the conditional and returns false.  However, the keyboard remains on the screen.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate{


func textView(textView: UITextView!, shouldChangeTextInRange: NSRange, replacementText: NSString!) -> Bool {
    if(replacementText.isEqualToString("\n")) {
        textBox.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

textBox is a delegate for the view.  I have connected this through Interface Builder.  Any ideas why it isn't dismissing the keyboard?

Comment: Have you set the delegate of the textbox to self?

Comment: At the bottom of the OP, I mention it is connected through IB.  I even added textBox.delegate = self in viewDidLoad() but still nothing.

Comment: @4thSpace try to change textBox to `textView.resignFirstResponder()`, see if it works

Comment: Use the textView that is passed in the delegate method instead of your property textBox.

Comment: Ah I missunderstood you. Do you have any other delegate methods like `textViewShouldEndEditing` in use which could stop the resignfirstresponder to work? Also have you tried using textView, the parameter of the delegate instead of your textBox?

Comment: Perfect! It should have been the passed in textView.  Can one of you post as answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dismiss keyboard for UITextView without using Return key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057242/dismiss-keyboard-for-uitextview-without-using-return-key)

Answer (score 0):

First of all please ensure that your My ViewController is a delegate of the textField,
And then, on the method `shouldChangeTextInRange` use the textView that is passed in the delegate method instead of your property textBox.

**For example:**

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate{

    func viewDidLoad(){
      super.viewDidLoad()
      textBox.delegate = self
    }

func textView(textView: UITextView!, shouldChangeTextInRange: NSRange, replacementText: NSString!) -> Bool {
    if(replacementText.isEqualToString("\n")) {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```